# How to build up a nested HTML Table using a KQL query in LogicApps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, kql

I'm facing an issue with slow performance in this post: [Slow performing triple Foreach with Parallelism taking up 40 minutes with LogicApps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925678/slow-performing-triple-foreach-with-parallelism-taking-up-40-minutes-with-logica), hence thinking of building the solution in a KQL query.

Situation: I have a Foreach Category within a Foreach of Products with a run time of 40 minutes. Basically it builds an HTML table for each Category, and within that category it places the Products together with the right Specialization.

Current setup:

- Foreach Category contains 5 items

  - Foreach Products contains 300 items

    - Foreach Specialization contains 5 items

The results are retrieved from Azure Log Analytics and stored in a LogicApp variable list which can be iterated. How can I build the above solution in to a KQL query?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can solve it with one list containing the category, products and specialization, for example:

```
datatable(Product:string, Category:string, Specialization:string)
[
"p1", "c1", "s1",
"p1", "c2", "s1", 
"p1", "c2", "s2", 
"p1", "c1", "s1",
"p2", "c2", "s1", 
"p2", "c2", "s2"
]
| summarize by Product, Category, Specialization
| order by Product asc, Category asc, Specialization asc
```

If the products, categories and specializations are in different tables use the "[lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator)" operator to join them together and then do the summarization followed by sort.